# Increment day by 1 every third iteration

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to increment the days in the date variable every third iteration using modulus.

I think I got the every third iteration right but the day doesn't increase by 1. I looked around and there was lots of suggestion to use `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);` and that's what I'm trying, but it doesn't produce the result I want. It increments once however the date doesn't increase beyond that.

Here's what I have tried code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let date = new Date();
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are reassigning `date` after every iteration in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require, consider moving the `date` variable outside of the loop as shown below. Please also see the documentation in the snippet below for detail on how this works and why:

```js
/* 
Consider shifting "date" outside of loop. This
will give you a reference point on which the
increment can be accumulated during iteration
*/
let date = new Date();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 
  if (i % 3 == 0) {

    /*
    Increment the day of the date object that
    is outside of the loop. Because the date
    object is defined outside of the loop, this
    causes the increments to be "remembered" 
    between loop iterations
    */
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating a new `Date` object in every iteration of the loop. In order to fix this, you just have to move the declaration of `date` outside of it like this:

```js
let date = new Date();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare date outside of your loop. You are resetting it everytime.

```js
let date = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: How could I be so blind!? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is because you define your `date` variable every time you loop, move that outside

```js
let date = new Date();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(i, date);
  }
}
```